# How to determine statistical significance of a study with multiple A/B questions?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, excel

I ran a survey that gives participants multiple A/B pairs (16 pairs). For each of the pairs, I ask the participant to select Option A or Option B. Therefore, I have 16 responses per participant. The sample size of the survey is 50 participants.

Overall, participants selected Option A over Option B for 80% of the time (an average of 12.8 out of 16 pairs). I also have the data for each individual participant. How do I determine if Option A is statistically significant from Option B (e.g. for p < 0.01)? I would like to use Excel or R. What test(s) do I run and how?

Comment: If you have data for all the answers for each participant you should probably include this in your analysis, participant would be a blocking variable or a random variable, so as to include participant variability.

Comment: @user2974951 What test would you recommend to do to factor in participant variability? I am not familiar with blocking variable. Thanks.